# How can I list the names of directories that contain file names matching a pattern?

Tags: files, find, osx

Given a directory `X` that contains several subdirectories and files, I would like to list the names of the immediate child directories of `X` that (directly or indirectly) contain file names matching the regex `^rf.*\.img$`.

How can this be achieved on OS X?

Comment: Which OS? You probably have `find` installed, which version?

Comment: I'm on OSX, but it seems as though `find` doesn't have a `-v` flag, or equivalent.  How should I check the version?

Comment: Ok, just see if `find` supports `-regex`: `man find | grep -e -regex`

Comment: @muru: no such luck

Comment: Ok, however, in your case the filename can be expressed using wildcard patterns: `rf*.img`. So would be fine with that?

Comment: Yes, that would be a perfectly acceptable approach (in fact, it's better since it's simpler.)

Comment: OSX `find` [definitely supports `-regex` primary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html).

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `find`, you can test each directory:

```sh
for i in "$dir"/*/
do
    test -n "$(find "$i" -type f -regex '.*/test[^/]*' -print -quit)" \
       && echo "$i"
done
```

This searches each directory for a file beginning `test` and prints the directory if it's found.

A couple of things to note:

1. I'm ignoring subdirectories that begin with `.`; if they need to be considered, check the Bash FAQ for how to include them without also catching `.` and `..`.
2. We exit `find` early, using `-quit` when we get a match.  This may save time in large filesystem trees.
3. The `-regex` test matches against the whole pathname considered by `find`, so if we just want to match against the basename, we need to be careful about matching `/`.  We can match on wildcard patterns without this restriction (and without requiring GNU find), using `-filename`.
4. You can use `-iregex` instead of `-regex` for a case-insensitive match.
5. You can select the regex syntax using `-regextype` option.

For the specific pattern in the question, we can use wildcards, so it becomes:

```sh
for i in "$dir"/*/
do
    test -n "$(find "$i" -type f -name 'rf*.img' -print -quit)" && echo "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` (assuming you're already in `X`):

```
typeset -U subdirs
subdirs=(*/**/rf*.img(.e_'REPLY=${REPLY%%/*}'_))
print -rl -- "${subdirs[@]}"
```

Here  `*/**/rf*.img` globs for all `rf*.img` files in all subdirectories, the glob qualifiers `.` and `e` select only regular files and respectively save only the first component of the path in an array that was initially defined as an array with unique elements (so no duplicates). It then prints each element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list using [`find`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) and pipe that through [`grep`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html):

```
(cd X && find . -type d -maxdepth 1 | sed -e 's,^./,,' | grep -E '^rf.*\.img$' )
```

I used a subshell to get just the names inside `X`; otherwise one would need to account for the path in `find`.

If you want subdirectories recursively, you can omit the `-maxdepth 1` option.  But then that means you would have to adjust the regular expression, e.g.,

```
(cd X && find . -type d | sed -e 's,^./,,' | grep -E '^(.*/)?rf.*\.img$' )
```

and in that case, the sed command is redundant (but harmless).

Comment: This is 99% correct, but I was a bit unclear:  the child directories of `X` also have child directories of their own, which may contain the files I'm trying to match.  To be clear:  I am only looking to list the names of `X`'s children, however, so that part is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use neither `grep` nor `ls`, but `find`:

```
find . -name 'rf*.img'
```

GNU `find` has an option to print just the directory (`-printf "%h\n"`), but in your case, that's not an option.

You could do something like:

```
find . -name 'rf*.img' | sed 's:/[^/]*$::'
```

If you want just the first directory, maybe something like:

```
find . -name 'rf*.img' -exec dirname {} \; | sed 's:./\([^/]*\).*:\1:'
```

Comment: That's a glob, which doesn't correspond exactly to the regex.  (OP may still accept though).

Comment: I like this approach -- it's much simpler than a regex.  One small problem: it's listing the full path, and I only want the first-level child of the current working directory.  Is there a fix for this?  i.e., it prints `./2015_02_17_THRESHOLD_Pilote01/S15_MBB3_ep2d_TR_900_3iso_Run6` whereas I only want `./2015_02_17_THRESHOLD_Pilot01`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I think [they would](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243292/how-can-i-list-the-names-of-directories-that-contain-files-matching-a-regex#comment417381_243292). But where does this pattern differ from the regex?

Comment: @blz I thought that's what you wanted! :D I really wish you had GNU find. See update

Answer (score 0):

Use `perl` and its `grep` and `glob`.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @file_list = grep { /^rf.*\.img$/ } glob "*";
print join ( "\n", @file_list );
```

Or as a one-liner:

```perl
perl -e 'print join ( "\n", grep { /^rf.*\.img$/ } glob "*" )'
```

Note - `glob` does shell-style wildcard expansions, so you can `glob "*/*/name/*"` or similar. If you need an arbitrary recursion depth, you might want to use `File::Find` instead:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

sub print_match {
    #Default match is against $_ which is filename. 
    #can match $File::Find::name for full name.
    #or $File::Find::dir
    print if  /^rf.*\.img$/;
}

find ( \&print_match, "/path/to/search" );
```

As a one-liner again:

```perl
perl -MFile::Find -e 'find ( sub { print if  /^rf.*\.img$/ }, "/my/path/to/search" );'
```